# Popup page without internet connection using coova-chilli

Tags: popup, wifi, router, openwrt, coovachilli

I am using **openwrt and coovachilli** for registration purpose, when there is presence of internet connection to router then chilli starts and **popup page** appears after connect to WiFi.
 But I want **popup page** without presence of internet. Router should popup after connect to WiFi using **coovachilli** without **internet**. Please help me out in this situation.
Thanks in advance.

OpenWrt Version:- 15.05
CoovaChilli Version:- 1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible technically due to the way Coova Chilli (and other hotspot software systems) works.

Without Internet connection, your DNS server will return failures so no DNS query will work. Without DNS queries (and IP addresses as result), there won't be a HTTP request for Coova to hijack. Your device (eg. iPhone) won't even trigger a CNA window

There are possibilities (workarounds) of course - eg. make your DNS resolver (dnsmasq?) resolve to some dummy/hardcoded IP address while the connection is down. You would have to write a script yourself that detects connection and swaps configs

Comment: Hello @denis thanks for your reply, but I did this possible, I made so many changes in chilli configuration file and also installed dns server in it.

Comment: @VishalRabadiya what does your DNS server return when the connection is down? Some static/hard-coded IP address for any domain?

Comment: Hello @denisMysenko sorry no need to install dns server, you have to make changes in /etc/host file and in /etc/resolv.conf as well to redirect it to our portal page. If you want I can provide to my configuration details. Yes, I redirect it to my router ip address(192.168.0.1)

Comment: @VishalRabadiya please provide your configuration details

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with a workaround.

You have to use a local UAM server (on the same host or LAN) and authenticate with local users file or local RADIUS server. For using local users file, without RADIUS server, you must specify a dummy RADIUS server IP:

```
radiusserver1 127.0.0.1
localusers /etc/chilli/localusers
```

Then, you can add a `dummyuser:dummypass` to your `localusers` file and use it for the authentication as usual:

```
http://${uam_ip}:${uam_port}/logon?username=dummyuser&password=${chap_password}
```